# Error al descomprimir archivo .zip

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, zip

Estoy tratando de descomprimir un archivo .zip en mi aplicación hecha en cordova para android  pero me marca el siguiente error:

> ```
> cordova.callbackFromNative('Zip1655561780',false,9,["An error occurred while unzipping."], false);
> ```

Mi código es:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    // When the user clicks some button to select the file
    $$('#btn-actualizar').on('click',function(){

      processZip('file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/emoji.zip', "/storage/emulated/0");
    });
}

function processZip(zipSource, destination){
    // Handle the progress event
    var progressHandler = function(progressEvent){
        var percent =  Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);

        // Display progress in the console : 8% ...
        console.log(percent + "%");
    };

    // Proceed to unzip the file
    window.zip.unzip(zipSource, destination, (status) => {
        if(status == 0){
            console.log("Archivo Extraido Satisfactoriamente...");
        }

        if(status == -1){
            console.error("Error, No es Posible Extraer El Archivo...");
        }
    }, progressHandler);
}
```

En consola manda lo siguiente:

```
Error, No es Posible Extraer El Archivo...
    window.zip.unzip    @   actualizarApp.js:31
fail    @   zip.js:24
callbackFromNative  @   cordova.js:293
(anonymous) @   VM88:1  //de aquí sale el error antes mencionado
```

Answer (score 0):

asegúrate de que el archivo zip esta en perfectas condiciones, prueba a descomprimirlo con Winrar y con 7zip en cualquier sistema operativo windows.